# Upsource with TeamCity build on Pull request

Tags: teamcity, bitbucket, jetbrains-ide, upsource

I have project hosted on Bitbucket and I'm using Upsource for reviews/pull requests. Is there a way how to setup TeamCity to build branch which is on review?
I saw guide fro the Github which is sadly not applicable to Bitbucket since adding `+:refs/pull/*/merge` didn't change anything.

I would like to have work-flow like this.

1. Create review
2. TeamCity runs build
3. Icon in Upsource indicates that build was ok